# How do I access my google user profile on Heroku using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, heroku, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I have a Ruby program that automates simple data entry tasks for a web application with Selenium-Chromedriver. In order for the program to work, I need to create a chromedriver instance that starts out as logged in to my google account, because the web application doesn't let you log in if it doesn't recognize that the browser is being used by someone familiar. To meet these criteria, I set up the driver like this:

```
args = ['user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data']
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: args)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)
$browser = Watir::Browser.start("https://nycseminarcenter.tripleseat.com/calendar", driver)
```

I want to add this program to a collection of other programs I have on Heroku that are scheduled to automatically run every so often, and I installed the buildpacks that should let me use Selenium from Heroku (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome and https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver), but when I try to run the program as is, I end up with the following error

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:72:in `assert_ok': unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)  
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux 4.4.0-1038-aws x86_64)
```

coming from the line where I create the Webdriver object. I'm guessing that the "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist" because Heroku doesn't have a copy of my user data directory like my local ruby environment does. Is there some special way to access a google user profile directly on Heroku?

Comment: I've read that adding other command line switches like disable-gpu, no-sandbox, and headless can prevent certain related errors, but are those things really necessary for a program like mine to work?

Comment: What did you set `user-data-dir` to?  The user data directory on the Heroku instance?  I'd think that would be `~/.config/google-chrome` on linux.

Comment: I think I just set user-data-dir to a location on my C drive. Heroku has it's own user data directory? How do I get the filepath to it/figure out where to find it?

Comment: My first comment shouldn't be relevant because "This buildpack installs shims that always add --headless, --disable-gpu, --no-sandbox, and --remote-debugging-port=9222 to any google-chrome command as you'll have trouble running Chrome on a Heroku dyno otherwise."

Comment: Try SSH'ing to your heroku instance and look for the `~/.config/google-chrome` directory.  That's chrome's default location for the user data directory.

Comment: I figured out how to set user-data-dir to the ~/.config/google-chrome directory when my app is running on Heroku, but how do I put an actual google profile into that directory?

Comment: I tried getting to that folder with Heroku Bash, but the .config folder doesn't seem to exist there.

Comment: @CoreyShapiro Did you figure this out? I wanted to try out importing my chrome cache data into the selenium bot so that I don't have to make an authentication to log into my whatsapp account through selenium